# Comparing two lists each elements together

Tags: python, list

I want to compare two lists (list a and list b).

For example:

```
list a = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]

list b = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
```

if we have...

```
a1 == b1
a2 == b2
a3 == b3
a4 == b4
a5 == b5
```

Result: 5

Other example:

```
list 1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list 2 = [1, 7, 9, 4, 5]
```

Result: 3

Can anybody suggest how to do this in python?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generator expression.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1, 7, 9, 4, 5]

num_equal = sum(i == j for i, j in zip(list1, list2))
print(num_equal)  # 3
```

`zip(list1, list2)` returns an iterator containing tuples of each value in `list1` and `list2`, essentially forming pairs of corresponding items from the two lists:

```py
print(list(zip(list1, list2)))  # [(1, 1), (2, 7), (3, 9), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

You can then check if each pair is equal or not in a list comprehension, creating a list of `True` or `False`:

```py
print([i == j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)])  # [True, False, False, True, True]
```

You can take the `sum` of this list, as `True` casts to the integer `1` and `False` casts to the integer `0`. Note that we can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (leave out the `[]`) in the `sum` call to be more memory-efficient.

Comment: It would be even better to omit the `[]` and pass a *generator expression* to `sum`, to avoid building up an unnecessary list in memory.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I am just used to adding the `[]`. I'll add your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over both lists and check if the values are the same:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1, 7, 9, 4, 5]

same = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):  # assuming the lists are the same length
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
        same += 1

print(same)
```

Output: `3`

Comment: `range(len(...))` is occasionally necessary, but it's a code smell. In this case it indicates you could reach for [`zip`](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/#zip).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a different approach. If both numbers equal then both are substrated the value will be zero. So, we can count the value of zero.

NB: This approach will only work for numbers.

```
In [13]: list(map(int.__sub__, list1, list2)).count(0)
Out[13]: 3
```